# Getting select's option value in onChange function of CKEDITOR's plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

So, for example, I have CKEDITOR plugin

```js
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('internallink', {
    icons: 'internallink',
    toolbar: 'insert,100',

    init: function (editor) {
      
        editor.addCommand('internallink', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('internalLinkDialog'));

        editor.ui.addButton('InternalLink', {
            label: 'Internal link',
            command: 'internallink',
            toolbar: 'links'
        });

        CKEDITOR.dialog.add('internalLinkDialog', function (editor) {

            return {
                title: 'Internal link',
                minWidth: 600,
                minHeight: 400,
                contents: [
                    {
                        id: 'tab-main',
                        label: 'Select page',
                        elements: [
                            {
                                type: 'select',
                                id: 'page_tree',
                                label: 'Select page',
                                items: [[1],[2],[3]],
                                onChange: function() {
                                  ...
                                }
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                onShow: function () {
                    ...

                },
                onOk: function () {
                    ...
                },
            };
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see, there is select item with options.
And when I've selected one of select's options, I need to display this value.
How can I get this value in

```js
onChange: function () {
  ...
}
```

Tell me, please, how can I do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solition is:

```js
onChange: function() {
  alert( 'Current value: ' + this.getValue() );
}
```

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.select